# Automate build process of minGW/msys using script like ANT

Tags: ant, mingw, msys

I am having a C++ project in windows XP. I am compiling this project using minGW/msys.
I want to automate this task using some scriping language like ANT.
but I could not google it. 
Please help me to automate minGW/msys compilation on windows.

Comment: No need to put your entire question body in **bold**. Your question is not more special or deserves any more special attention than the others.

Comment: If this is a C++ project, why not use Make instead of Ant? Make is designed for C++ compilation since you must both compile and link your code. Ant is made for Java which all you have to do is compile and not link.

Comment: @Nitin, Don't edit answers to ask further questions and clarify your problem. Edit instead your question.

Answer (score 0):

`make` is the established tool to do this and actually the blueprint for ant (which was started to be a syntax-simplified make and is now a horrible mess, just like everything Java, but that's beside the main point). To simplify program site configuration and Makefile generation, see `autoconf` and `automake`.